# Using CanCanCan for Roles and Multiple Devise Models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, cancancan

I need to use CanCanCan to limit the ability for all users to only be able to view their own data, or allow limited data to be seen from others.

I have tried the following but doesn't work:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

      def initialize(user)

        user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
        affiliate ||= Affiliate.new # guest user (not logged in)
        # guest ||= U
        #Admin
        if user.admin?
          can :manage, :all

        elsif user.seller?
            can :manage, Listing, user_id: user.id
            can :read, Listing
            can :manage, Order, buyer_id: user.id
            can :manage, Order, seller_id: user.id
            can :manage, StripeAccount, user_id: user.id

            can :manage, BankAccount, user_id: user.id
            can :manage, User, user_id: user.id

        elsif affiliate
            can :manage, User, affiliate_id: affiliate.id
            can :read, Order
            can :manage, StripeAccount, affiliate_id: affiliate.id
            can :manage, Affiliate, affiliate_id: affiliate.id


        #Buyer
        elsif user.buyer?
          can :read, Listing
          can [:create, :read, :edit, :purchases, :update], Order, buyer_id: user.id

        #Guest
        else
          can :read, Listing
          can [:create, :order_confirmation], Order
          # can :create, User
        end
      end
    end
```

When i am signed in as an affiliate, it won't let me view the StripeAccount associated with the affiliate.id, and it is there in the model.

I have two models, User and Affiliate.

User has roles as enum, 1,2,3. (admin is 3)
Affiliate has roles as enum, 1,2

I need to set limitation for each devise model and each role within each devise model.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have solved it, still testing:

```
private

  def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, current_affiliate)
  end
```

then with:

```
def initialize(user, affiliate)
```